# How to set the value attribute for select items in vaadin

Tags: java, internationalization, vaadin

- I am using a login form (LoginOverlay) from vaadin to login to my application.
- I use the custom form area to add a language select box where the language can be selected
- The form is then posted to a security service which is not under vaadins control (Quarkus)
- Vaadin uses indexes to represent the language values
- I am aware of the fact that this is the usual way it is done in vaadin and i generally understand why

How can i make vaadin use iso 2-letter codes as the value of the select items so the security service knows the language exactly.

```java
Select<Locale> select = new Select<>();
select.setId("language");
select.getElement().setAttribute("name", "language");
select.setItems(Locale.GERMAN, Locale.ENGLISH);
```

Version: Vaadin flow: 24.3.1

Answer (score 0):

Change the Select's generic type from `Locale` to `String`. That's how you can define the item values to be the Strings you want. Then you can use `setItemLabelGenerator` to set the labels.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to add a `<select ...><option .../></select>` in your
form, you have to go outside of what is coming with Flow.  The form
elements are often not meant to be used in the classic `<form>`-tag
environment.

This said, if you don't want to put the whole thing into "real HTML" or
don't want to create a web-component, it's quite easy to create
something inside the DOM with Flow.

```
ElementFactory.createSelect().tap {
    setAttribute('name', 'language')
    [Locale.ENGLISH, Locale.GERMAN].each { lang ->
        appendChild(
                ElementFactory.createOption(lang.getDisplayName(Locale.ROOT)).tap {
                    setAttribute('value', lang.language)
                }
        )
    }
}
```

Other sources for inspiration might be using the `Html`-class and bang
the HTML together yourself.  Or take a look at
https://github.com/vaadin/flow/blob/main/flow-tests/test-embedding/embedding-test-assets/src/main/java/com/vaadin/flow/webcomponent/Select.java
which shows how to create a proper field as `select`.